# typical TFIDF range?

Tags: text-mining, tf-idf

Forgive me if this is the wrong place for my question. My question is, I hope fairly straightforward. Although I am using Rstudio and the TM package, I think my question is more about the math behind the TFIDF score and is similar to an older question ([Typical range of values for TFIDF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165104/typical-range-of-values-for-tfidf)) but the answer was only partial.

As an example say I have a corpus of 2000 news articles that all contain the word "cat". I used the TFIDF weighting on my Document-Term-Matrix and as expected "cat" receives a low score because it is in every document. However, "dog" appears in 60% of these articles also and it gets a TFIDF score of ~25.0. I would expect that it would have a higher score a long with words like 'tail' (~12.0) etc... but I was under the impression that the scores should be more along the 0-1.0 range rather than something as high as 25!

Basically my returned results match my assumptions, but being that I am new to Text Mining and TFIDF I want to make sure its not a coincidence and that these scores do make sense.

Sorry it is not really replicable, but does a TFIDF score as high as 25 sound plausible?

Comment: I once asked something similar : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165104/typical-range-of-values-for-tfidf

Comment: Hi @RUser4512, thanks, thats why I referenced the question in mine. The problem was there was just an answer to part 2 of your question about dropping low freq words. I am more curious about the 1st part...i just dont quite understand if a TFIDF score of 25 make sense.